# how to recognise a zebra crossing from top view using opencv?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, robotics

you can get all the details about the problem from this pdf document: www.shaastra.org/2013/media/events/70/Tab/422/Modern_Warfare_ps_v1.pdf

how to recognize a zebra crossing from top view using opencv ?? 
it is not a straight zebra crossing it has some twists and turns
i have some ideas,
1. parallel line detection but the available techniques only works to find straight parallel not the ones that has curve in it.
2. template matching to match a template of back to back white and black stripes but it becomes tedious since i cant find any pattern matching techniques with scaling and rotation.

in fact a idea on any single part of the problem will be so helpful!!
it is driving me crazy someone please help!!!!
any help is appreciated 
thanks in advance ....

NOTE:
 the zebra crossing i am talking about has the inside lines perpendicular to the border lines, just like a normal zebra crossing. only difference is that the path has curves like a river

Comment: I'd put some research into recognizing a zebra from Hough transform.

Comment: cool idea @Algebra but i really don't want to get that deep to detect a zebra ,and also the zebra crossing i am talking about has the inside lines perpendicular to the border lines, just like a normal zebra crossing only difference is that the path has curves like a river ............                        any way thank you

Answer (score 4):

I'd have a look at [Haar-like features](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/objdetect_cascade_classification.html) as a low level descriptor. It is very commonly used in [face detection](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/FaceDetection) but is a technique with wide applications.

Some of the very common features are sensitive to lines; vertical, horizontal, or diagonal. These should be well suited to detecting zebra crosswalks. Also, depending on your implementation, these feature sets can be scale insensitive which would make your algorithm more robust.

A large number of parallel lines with such contrast (white (or yellow) paint vs pavement) should get you on your way to recognizing zebra crossings. I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'twists and turns' as zebra crossings, by design, are supposed to be straight. If you provide an image or two of your edge cases, perhaps we can brainstorm with you.

**Edit:**
I also agree strongly with @Algebra's comment. Using a Hough transform, you could get the edges of the lines. A number of parallel lines at regular intervals should be a strong indication of a zebra crossing.

For whichever approach(es) you explore, you will want to use machine learning techniques for pattern recognition to make the final decision on what a zebra crossing looks like. You do not want to  hard code things like 'x parallel lines of y width and z length'.

Comment: you can get all the details about the problem from this pdf document: www.shaastra.org/2013/media/events/70/Tab/422/Modern_Warfare_ps_v1.pdf                                        and the zebra crossing i am talking about has the inside lines perpendicular to the border lines, just like a normal zebra crossing.only difference is that the path has curves like a river thanks for the idea going through that........

Comment: and actually the curved zebra crossing will always be in a perfect scale black and white stripes 25 mm each and the path is 250 mm width

Comment: This is for a robotics competition? With a physical game space, yeah? If so, I'd highly suggest getting images from the perspective of your robot. The competition may provide these, you could build a physical model of the game space yourself, or maybe generate mock images using a 3d modeling tool. The point being, you will the perspective of your robot will change how you design your algorithm. If its a top-down flying robot thats a different problem than a robot that's low to the ground and looking forward. In either case you'll probably be using edge detection, pattern recognition, etc.

Comment: Also, take a look at the Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HOG) and similar feature descriptor algorithms. They might help in recognizing the zebra crossing at different angles.

Comment: yes this is for a robotics competition. surely  the perspective of the robot changes a lot but for the due to accuracy , hard deadline and all other stuffs ,which one will be easier to program the on-board camera or the top view camera ?? and also you might have seen that the robot has to process some obstacles along its path

Comment: I'd imagine the top-down view would be 'easiest' to process. In the sense that the information you aim to pull from it will be *changing less* than from the first-person perspective. In the latter, each frame will be different. In the former, you just need to analyze the current state of the game board, the layout of which you already know. Your goal, then, is to detect the obstacles and your character, make them interact, and track the results.

Comment: exactly. so i can find the obstacles and my robot using a color filters and blob areas, and direct my robot by programming it to stay on the center line of the track and when the center of robot and obstacle is in a certain distance it can stop and pickup the object .............................................................  hence but the major problem is how can I detect the track that too a only one time calculation at the starting of the match. NOW READING ALL THE METHODS YOU HAVE SUGGESTED ............. THANKS AGAIN

Comment: now @sean the Haar-like features gets me no where, so please anymore detailed description of what you have in mind will be helpful!!

Comment: Well, now, we've strayed far from the Q/A format of StackOverflow. If this topic has spurred any more questions (which I hope it has) please open new, directed, questions. I'll keep an eye out, an you'll spark new interest from others also. Cheers.

Comment: now I thought that the following way would be much easier way to detect it,

(i) canny it

(ii) find the contours in it

(iii) find the black stripes in it, in my case it is slightly oval in shape
take a look at the images of the zebra crossing to get the shape
now my question is how to find that slightly oval shape??

Comment: @user1929880.. long discussions like this are discouraged, please open new questions if you want answers.

Comment: okay okay here is my new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055676/how-to-find-shapes-that-are-slightly-elongated-oval-rectangle-with-curved-corn

Answer (score 2):

Here is a relevant paper:

[Detecting and Locating Crosswalks using a Camera Phone](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2874980/)

While this is not an opencv implementation it should be a reasonable place to start.

Comment: Reading this paper, and another one of their papers that they site it appears that their algorithm is tuned for straight zebra striped cross walks.  Still, this may be a good start.

Comment: it seems really helpful and also reminds me that even to solve this problem I still have a lot to learn !!