# how to find shapes that are slightly elongated oval / rectangle with curved corners / sometimes sector of a circle?

Tags: opencv, pattern-matching, computer-vision, robotics, contour

[how to recognise a zebra crossing from top view using opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041109/how-to-recognise-a-zebra-crossing-from-top-view-using-opencv)

in my previous question the problem is to find the curved zebra crossing using opencv.
now I thought that the following way would be much easier way to detect it,

(i)   canny it

(ii)  find the contours in it

(iii) find the black stripes in it, in my case it is slightly oval in shape

now my question is how to find that slightly oval shape??

look here for images of the crossing: www.shaastra.org/2013/media/events/70/Tab/422/Modern_Warfare_ps_v1.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, I believe there are two approaches you can consider.

One approach is the more brute force *image analysis* approach, as you described. Here you are applying heuristics based on your knowledge of the problem in order to identify the pixels involved in the parts of the path. Note that 'brute force' here is not a bad thing, just an adjective.

An alternative approach is to apply *pattern recognition* techniques to find the regions of the image which have high probability of being part of the path. Here you would be transforming your image into (hopefully) meaningful features: lines, points, gradient (eg: [Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HOG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients)), relative intensity (eg: [Haar-like features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_features)) etc. and using *machine learning* techniques to figure out how these features describe the, say, the road vs the tunnel (in your example).

As you are asking about the former, I'm going to focus on that here. If you'd like to know more about the latter have a look around the Internet, StackOverflow, or post specific questions you have.

So, for the 'brute force image analysis' approach, your first step would *probably* be to preprocess the image as you need;

- Consider color normalization if you are going to analyze color later, this will help make your algorithm robust to lighting differences in your garage vs the event studio. It'll also improve robustness to camera collaboration differences, though the organization hosting the competition provide specs for the camera they will use (don't ignore this bit of info).
- Consider blurring the image to reduce noise if you're less interested in pixel by pixel values (eg edges) and more interested in larger structures (eg gradients).
- Consider sharpening the image for the opposite reasons of blurring.
- Do a bit of research on image preprocessing. It's definitely an explored topic but hardly 'solved' (whatever that would mean). There are lots of things to try at this stage and, of course, crap in => crap out.

After that you'll want to generate some 'features'..

- As you mentioned, **edges** seem like an appropriate feature space for this problem. Don't forget that there are many other great edge detection algorithms out there other than Canny (see [Prewitt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prewitt_operator), [Sobel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator), etc.) After applying the edge detection algorithm, though, you still just have pixel data. To get to *features* you'll want probably want to extract lines from the edges. This is where the [Hough transform space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) will come in handy.
- (Also, as an idea, you can think about colorspace in concert with the edge detectors. By that, I mean, edge detectors usually work in the B&W colorspace, but rather than converting your image to grayscale you could convert it to an appropriate colorspace and just use a single channel. For example, if the game board is red and the lines on the crosswalk are blue, convert the image to HSV and grab the hue channel as input for the edge detector. You'll likely get better contrast between the regions than just grayscale. For bright vs. dull use the value channel, for yellow vs. blue use the Opponent colorspace, etc.)
- You can also look at **points**. Algorithms such as the Harris corner detector or the Laplacian of Gaussian (LOG) will extract 'key points' (with a different definition for each algorithm but generally reproducible).
- There are many other feature spaces to explore, don't stop here.

Now, this is where the brute force part comes in..

- The first thing that comes to mind is parallel lines. Even in a curve, the edges of the lines are 'roughly' parallel. You could easily develop an algorithm to find the track in your game by finding lines which are each roughly parallel to their neighbors. Note that line detectors like the Hough transform are usually applied such that they find 'peaks', or overrepresented angles in the dataset. Thus, if you generate a Hough transform for the whole image, you'll be hard pressed to find any of the lines you want. Instead, you'll probably want to use a sliding window to examine each area individually.
- Specifically speaking to the curved areas, you can use the Hough transform to detect circles and elipses quite easily. You could apply a heuristic like: two concentric semi-circles with a given difference in radius (~250 in your problem) would indicate a road.
- If you're using points/corners you can try to come up with an algorithm to connect the corners of one line to the next. You can put a limit on the distance and degree in rotation from one corner to the next that will permit rounded turns but prohibit impossible paths. This could elucidate the edges of the road while being robust to turns.

You can probably start to see now why these hard coded algorithms start off simple but become tedious to tweak and often don't have great results. Furthermore, they tend to rigid and inapplicable to other, even similar, problems.

**All that said..** you're talking about solving a problem that doesn't have an out of the box solution. Thinking about the solution is half the fun, and half the challenge. Everything I've described here is basic image analysis, computer vision, and problem solving. Start reading some papers on these topics and the ideas will come quickly. Good luck in the competition.