# Recognizing crosswalk on aerial images

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, classification, object-detection

I'm trying to find x/y coordinates of crosswalks on aerial images.

For example on this image:

[image]

...I'd like to extract two nodes in the center of the two yellow crosswalks.

I started playing around with OpenCV on Python. The first approach I tried was to isolate the yellow colored parts in the image. The results are not perfect though.

[image]

As the pattern of a crosswalk is quite unique, I think there should be a way to quite reliably detect the presence and the coordinates of a crosswalk. As I don't have much experience with image processing, can you give me some pointers in the right directions, with a small example? Maybe I should work with FFT, or create a classifier?

Here's the code I used for the screenshot above.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

# Create a window
cv2.namedWindow('image')

# Create trackbars
cv2.createTrackbar('H-', 'image', 16, 180, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('H+', 'image', 25, 180, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('S-', 'image', 40, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('S+', 'image', 150, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('V-', 'image', 97, 255, nothing)
cv2.createTrackbar('V+', 'image', 172, 255, nothing)

while 1:
    # Choose image
    img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('img/1.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # Get slider values
    h = cv2.getTrackbarPos('H-', 'image'), cv2.getTrackbarPos('H+', 'image')
    s = cv2.getTrackbarPos('S-', 'image'), cv2.getTrackbarPos('S+', 'image')
    v = cv2.getTrackbarPos('V-', 'image'), cv2.getTrackbarPos('V+', 'image')

    # Thresholds
    lower = np.array([h[0], s[0], v[0]], np.uint8)
    upper = np.array([h[1], s[1], v[1]], np.uint8)

    # Calculate mask using thresholds
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)

    # Combine original image and mask
    h, w = img.shape[:2]
    vis = np.zeros((h, w * 2), np.uint8)
    vis = cv2.cvtColor(vis, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    vis[:h, :w] = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_HSV2BGR)
    vis[:h, w:w * 2] = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    # Show image
    cv2.imshow('image', vis)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:  # ESC
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041109/how-to-recognise-a-zebra-crossing-from-top-view-using-opencv) is a similar discussion with many ideas that could help.

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at barcode code to see how they detect the position of a barcode, without actually reading it...

Comment: Are all these images acquired at the same height?  I.e., can one expect a certain scale from the crossings?

Comment: @StefanvanderWalt yes, possibly. right now it's not a constraint, but i could make it one.

Comment: If you know the scale, you can do template matching (skimage has that implemented).  You'll have to try and match several orientations of the crosswalk.  I would also do it in the appropriate color band, perhaps (e.g., convert to HSV color space and suppress all colors that aren't yellow).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a simple segmentation task since there are multiple orientations, complex backgrounds, and other objects with similar color distribution. As mentioned in the comment [Haar features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar-like_features) are very descriptive for this pattern. [Road feature detection and estimation](http://stephense.com/research/papers/mva03.pdf) Stephen Se and Michael Brady discusses that the crosswalk edges are interesting features they are usually straight lines with periodic intervals. One could use the hough transform to accumulate lines and then filter lines with the slope variables to look for target patterns. This [Masters Thesis](http://students.asl.ethz.ch/upl_pdf/304-report.pdf) on Urban Artifacts Detection - Stefania Pedrazzi talks about the same feature: The main property of crosswalk stripes, also called zebra stripes, is bipolarity, i.e.
the alternation of bright and dark areas. Bipolarity causes high gradient values at
stripes' edges. For this reason, computing gradients and extracting lines will provide
a good starting point. Then, it will only remain to iterate row- and column-wise
through the image, checking the geometric structure of consecutive lines. *Though this is for lateral viewpoints*, one can still use the geometric features.

Comment: The Haar classifier is still being trained, it has been doing so since 2 days :) I'll let you know whether it works as soon as the training is finished.

Comment: Perhaps you could also have a look at the probabilistic Hough transform in scikit-image--it gives back short line segments.

Comment: @beedot The classifier took eight days to train, and does not work properly :( But it was probably an issue with the training images. Thanks anyways for the answer with many pointers to the (probably) right direction. I'll accept it for now, even without having any positive results yet.

Comment: Hey @DaniloBargen - its bad it doesnt work given that it is a fundamental geometric feature. What are the failures like and what is the case with different scalings of the foothpath pattern ?

Comment: Either it doesn't recognize anything, or it recognizes them where there are no crosswalks at all...

Comment: Have you tried testing it on an obvious case to see if there is a real classifier learnt ? Also there can be problems with your rotations, color and scaling. Probably getting it to work on simple cases first should be the first step.

Comment: How did you end up solving this?